# Core Data - Savings and sharing images via iCloud

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, icloud, tvos

I have an app that allows a user to either take photo or point to a photo on from their camera roll. This record must be peristed locally. A record consists of text and an image. Savings this data on a single device seems simple, as I can persist the link to the image or store the image locally in the file system if taken via camera.

Problem is how to share this record via iCloud to make record available to all instances of the app on multiple devices. I.e iPhone creates a record with an image, which is then available to view on iPad or Apple TV.

Is it efficient to store a UIImage in a Core Data record and make this available via iCloud? Many people saying not for local storage

My concern is this could potentially be some large quantities of data?
Does anyone have any thoughts on how to solve this issue?

Comment: You can also save images in MySQL but then again it is a bad practise.
How about saving the link in a column of your Core Data while the actual file will be in Amazon S3.
If the user will login via multiple devices he can get ALWAYS the same pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I´m working on a similar app, for me working with http://Parse.com is a solution.
If your user have an internet connection and can wait to upload the images/text files you can save it directly using Parse (with a fancy progress Bar!) But if you want to make it network-less proof, you might work as whatsapp. I mean using Core Data to save your files locally, then try to upload the imagens whenever there is internet available.
There are some others clouds DB you can use, but I´m familiar with this one.

Comment: Thanks - Ideally want a native solution

Answer (score 0):

You can upload  to iCloud using NSFileManager.
There is a complete [walkthrough](http://samvermette.com/312) on how to do that.